# como desenvolver codeigniter + tailwind sem npm run dev constantemente

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, tailwind

estou desenvolvendo um app codeigniter com tailwind + daisyui, porém a cada alteração de view preciso de "npm install", "npm run dev".
existe uma solução pra isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o nodemon.
Primeiramente instale-o (npm install nodemon -g).
Em seu package.json, insira: "start": "nodemon node/index.js" dentro de "scripts".

Para iniciar basta executar o comando npm start.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Tutorial de instalação e uso:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/workflow-nodemon-pt

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).